# Masking IP via CURL?

Tags: php, post, curl, libcurl, http-post

How would I mask the server's IP address using CURL? I have it sending POST requests. Thanks

Comment: is there a *legitimate* reason to want to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot mask or change your server IP address on a whim. However, if you had a pool of proxies you could use, I suppose that you could draw from them.

You could also check out [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/) as it may or may not be able to assist you in your goal.